# How can I create a PHP array from this serialized string?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a string which looks like this:

```
id_company=57&name=&address=&zip=&place=&phone=&mobile=&email=&birthdate=&birthplace=&bsn=&driver_expires=&role=&date_started=&contract=Tijdelijk&id_type=Paspoort&id_number=&id_expires=
```

Above example is empty for the most part (except id_company).

I serialize my form in jquery like this:

```
var $serialized = $form.serialize();
```

And in my php I do this:

```
$jsonemployee = unserialize($_POST['serialized']);
```

After that I try to print it because I expect an array:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($jsonemployee);
echo '</pre>';
```

But this shows me nothing.

I am 100% sure all data is passed, in my networktab I see the string being posted and if I just echo the string, it shows the string.

How can I create a PHP array from that string?

Comment: First thing to do is `var_dump($_POST['serialized'])`. If you don't see anything then that data was never sent to the server.

Comment: @JohnConde I see the string when I var_dump it. `string(185) "id_company=57&name=&address=&zip=&place=&phone=&mobile=&email=&birthdate=&birthplace=&bsn=&driver_expires=&role=&date_started=&contract=Tijdelijk&id_type=Paspoort&id_number=&id_expires="`

Comment: Do you know how to explode on for example '&'?. This will create an array for you.

Comment: @RonnieOosting Yes but shouldn't there be a PHP function that does all this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unserialize` is not for unserialising *that* format, it's the counterpart to [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize), which produces a very different result. To parse a *URL-encoded* string in PHP, use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str).

```
parse_str($_POST['serialized'], $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Of course, it's somewhat bizarre that you're sending a URL encoded string as `$_POST['serialized']`… You should send it as the one and only request body, and PHP will automatically parse it into `$_POST` and you won't have to do any of this.

Comment: Great! This is what I needed, thank you. - I'll accept in 9 minutes.

Comment: @twan Note that jQuery's `serialize()` and php's `serialize()` are completely unrelated and produce results that are nowhere near similar.

Comment: Yeah makes sense now, I thought they did the same thing @jeroen

Comment: This will not work well if any text has `&` symbol, is there anyone got the same issue ?

Comment: @Udara Post your own question with details. `&` needs to be correctly *encoded* in the first place, as it has a special meaning in URL-encoded strings.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to convert this string into an array by doing :

```
$myArray = explode("&",$_POST['serialized']);
```

i think that will work for you.